# How to Convert a Date time value with UTC offset into GMT in java 7

Tags: java, datetime, utc, gmt, date-conversion

I have a date time value 2016-12-21T07:48:36 with an offset of UTC+14. How to convert the datetime into equivalent standard GMT time.

I tried with `sampleDateFormat.parse()` method.But, I am not able to get the TimeZone object for UTC offset like.

```
sampleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+14:00"))
```

Please help me to convert the UTC datetime into standard GMT time in Java 7.

Comment: You know your problem is only that you used the unsupported "UTC+14". getTimeZone only knows the "GMT+xx" form

Comment: Where did you get the **+14** offset from?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you have the original date as a string. Do the following:

- Create a `SimpleDateFormat` and set the timezone to "GMT+14"
- Parse the string value. You get a `Date` object
- Set the timezone of the `SimpleDateFormat` to "UTC" (or use a different `SimpleDateFormat` instance)
- Format the date (if you want the result as a string as well)

Example:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class ConvertToUTC {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      String dateval = "2016-12-21T07:48:36";
      DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
      df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+14"));
      Date date = df.parse(dateval);

      System.out.println(df.format(date)); // GMT+14

      df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      System.out.println(df.format(date)); // UTC
  }
}
```

Comment: Whether day light saving component will be considered if we use GMT+offset instead of UTC+offset?

Comment: @GOPI The answer is correct. Your question only mentions fixed offsets (and it is equal if the prefix is GMT or UTC). So day-light-saving is irrelevant in the context of your question. Otherwise don't use fixed offsets but timezone identifiers like "Asia/Tokyo" etc.

Comment: Thanks Meno & Grodriguez!

Answer (score 2):

use "GMT+14:00" instead of "UTC+14:00"

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+14:00"));
final Date d = f.parse("2016-12-21T07:48:36");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(f.format(d)); // -> 2016-12-20T05:48:36
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-21T07:48:36" )        // Parse as a `LocalDateTime` given the lack of an offset or zone. *Not* an actual moment, only a rough approximation of potential moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.
             .atOffset( ZoneOffset.ofHours( 14 ) )  // Assign an offset-from-UTC as context, giving meaning to determine an actual point on the timeline.
             .toInstant()                           // Renders `Instant` object in UTC.
```

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. Much of the functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( 14 ); // fourteen hours ahead of UTC.
```

Parse the string as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) as it lacks any info about offset or zone. Your input is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, so no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-12-21T07:48:36" );
```

Apply the offset to the local date-time to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) an object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( offset );
```

From that, extract an `Instant` which is always in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
```

> instant.toString(): 2016-12-20T17:48:36Z

In [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), the value is a different date, the 20th instead of 21st.

See [live code at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/AIqVd1).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Technically an `Instant` is not "in" any timezone. It represents an offset from the epoch.

Comment: @OrangeDog Incorrect. An `Instant` is most certainly in UTC. To quote the class doc: “The epoch-seconds are measured from the standard Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z”. That `Z` is short for Zulu and means UTC. Without being defined as UTC an `Instant` would have no meaning.

Comment: Just because the representation of the epoch in the docs is in Z, doesn't mean that an `Instant` is. To quote the class doc: "this Java API defines its own time-scale, the Java Time-Scale".

Comment: We can also say: An `Instant` is anchored arithmetically on UTC-offset zero (absolutely necessary for any internal date-time-calculation), but for formatting purposes, an instant should never be used without a timezone or offset for representing local informations, and the `java.time`-API prevents this i.e. forces the user to specify a timezone or offset when formatting/parsing an instant (in most cases).